# stash apply causing merging conflict

Tags: git

I made a stash and then later I worked on another branch and committed changes.

now I want to get back to my normal stash and continue working on it and even commit work later.

what I used to get back to my stash is the following command :

```
git stash apply stash@{2}
```

everything worked fine , but there is 3 files that caused merge conflict .

```
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
```

what command should I use to restore these files into their stash state. (I don't want the current committed state) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "squash state"? (Is "squash" a typo for "stash" here?)

Comment: yes it's a typo , sorry for that .. I meant stash

Comment: Technically a stash is just a small set of commits. One can see it in a graphical view in `gitk --all`. So you can either jump right to the top commit of a stash with `git reset --hard <top-commit-of-the-stash>` or just hard reset your working branch to the last commit before the stash (again with `git reset --hard ....`) and then use `git stash pop`

Comment: My experience suggests that when a stash fails to apply cleanly, then most likely it's applied to a wrong place, e.g. one didn't change a working branch back to one that was active when the stash was created. Observing the "whole picture" in a graphical view, like `gitk --all` helps to understand the reason of the mistake and fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve merge conflicts in a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 0):

First, let me quote a bit of [the `git stash` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash):

> #### DISCUSSION
>
> A stash entry is represented as a commit whose tree records the state of the working directory, and its first parent is the commit at `HEAD` when the entry was created. The tree of the second parent records the state of the index when the entry is made, and it is made a child of the *HEAD* commit. The ancestry graph looks like this:
>
> ```
>        .----W
>       /    /
> -----H----I
> ```
>
> where `H` is the `HEAD` commit, `I` is a commit that records the state of the index, and `W` is a commit that records the state of the working tree.

The `stash` ref (`refs/stash`, or in your case, `stash@{2}`) then points the `W` commit.  I prefer to draw this as:

```
...--G--H   <-- branch (HEAD)
        |\
        i-w   <-- refs/stash
```

myself (showing the setup immediately after your `git stash push` command completes successfully), but the information here is the same.

**With that in mind:**  If you're quite certain you want your current working tree copy overwritten with the copy of the file in the `W` commit of `stash@{2}`, you can simply run:

```
git checkout stash@{2} -- path/to/file.ext
```

or:

```
git restore -SW --source=stash@{2} path/to/file.ext
```

Note that depending on your shell, the `stash@{2}` expression may need some kind of quoting, e.g., `--source='stash@{2}'`.

Note also that you can *view* this version of the file with:

```
git show stash@{2}:path/to/file.ext
```

before taking any other action.